# Why can't I say a question is off-topic and belongs on serverfault.com

Tags: discussion

I see many ?'s that should be on serverfault.com because they aren't about programming.

They are generally about dev ops issues. And most people on SO don't care for those questions, as most people on SO are programmers looking to help the community with PROGRAMMING PROBLEMS, generally, not dev ops issues.

Typically those questions are asked by IT people not software engineers. for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26288512/logging-mysqls-connections-it-doesnt-work

QUESTION: WHY CANT WE VOTE TO CLOSE QUESTIONS AS BELONGING ON ANOTHER SITE (SERVERFAULT.COM) for non programming related issues.

Answer (score 6):

The list of approved migration targets in the migration dialog is limited to those sites that:

1. Are the most common migration targets, and
2. Are the least abused by community members who don't understand the target site scope.

ServerFault didn't make the cut.

**See Also**
[Should Server Fault be removed from Stack Overflow's migration list?](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3853)

Comment: Did people use it as a toilet bowl or something (a la Programmers), or were people just misunderstanding the site scope?

Comment: @DennisMeng: See http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3853